# upgrading Mage_Core_Modules 1.8.1.0 to 1.9.0.1

Tags: magento

Hi i have this magento version which is 1.8.1.0 and i want to upgrade into the new version which is 1.9.0.1 Ive noticed that when i tried to upgrade the package name Mage_Core_Modules ive got thie error:

```
Already installed: community/Lib_Google_Checkout 1.8.1.0, skipping
Already installed: community/Lib_Js_Calendar 1.51.1.1, skipping
Already installed: community/Lib_Js_Mage 1.9.0.0, skipping
Already installed: community/Lib_Phpseclib 1.5.0.0, skipping
Already installed: community/Mage_Locale_en_US 1.9.0.0, skipping
Already installed: community/Mage_Locale_de_DE 1.9.0.0, skipping
Already installed: community/Mage_Locale_es_ES 1.9.0.0, skipping
Already installed: community/Mage_Locale_fr_FR 1.9.0.0, skipping
Already installed: community/Mage_Locale_nl_NL 1.9.0.0, skipping
Already installed: community/Mage_Locale_pt_BR 1.9.0.0, skipping
Already installed: community/Mage_Locale_zh_CN 1.9.0.0, skipping
Already installed: community/Lib_Mage 1.8.0.0, skipping
Already installed: community/Lib_Magento 1.9.0.0, skipping
Already installed: community/Lib_Credis 1.8.0.0, skipping
Already installed: community/Lib_ZF 1.12.7.0, skipping
Already installed: community/Lib_Js_Prototype 1.7.0.0.5, skipping
Already installed: community/Lib_ZF_Locale 1.12.7.0, skipping

CONNECT ERROR: Package community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.9.0.1 conflicts with: community/Magento_Mobile 1.8.0.0.23.1, community/Interface_Frontend_Base_Default 1.9.1.1, community/Mage_Compiler 1.9.1.1, community/Interface_Frontend_Rwd_Default 1.9.1.1, community/Mage_Core_Adminhtml 1.9.1.1, community/Interface_Install_Default 1.9.1.1, community/Mage_Centinel 1.9.1.1, community/Interface_Frontend_Default 1.9.1.1, community/Mage_All_Latest 1.9.1.1, community/Phoenix_Moneybookers 1.3.2.1
```

Can someone help me figured this thing out in upgrading the mage_core_modules to new version? Any help is muchly appreciated. TIA